# Event-Driven web service

Tags: android, web-services

I have implemented a home monitoring and control system with some motion detectors and temperature sensors, that is connected to a mini PC as a server. On this PC I have a .NET ASMX web service that has some methods, return the detectors situation and environment temperature.

In order to achieve the devices situation I am trying to build an Android application that can connect to the web service via Wifi and shows the temperatures.
when the temperature exceeds critical range or motion detectors detect motion, this application must show a related notification.

The problem here is: every time I need the system situation, I query the web service. but this way I have to query the web service every one second to know that whether the temperature exceeded critical range or not, and whether the detectors detected motion or not.
The question: is there any better solution to achieve this? or is there any way that a web service can inform the clients when an event occurs?

note that I am using KSOAP2 library in my android app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider using a Push notification pattern instead of polling the server to check for new data.

There are a few options here. The easiest and most standard would be to look into Google's push notification system, called Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Note that this is only available to devices which have Google Services (so if you're using a Kindle Fire for example, you can't use it)

Or you could consider a more bespoke version of push notifications based on MQTT protocol. You'll need to setup your own MQTT server, and have android code and server code which talks to the MQTT server.

Any time the data changes, you would send a push notification to the subscribing clients so they would not have to be checking for data all the time.

Comment: I found another solution but I'm not sure, so correct me if I'm wrong. Maybe I could use socket programming instead of using web service. by listening on specific port on both side and by defining my own communication protocol, I can send my messages from server to client or vice versa.

Comment: Yes that's correct, but it means that you'll have a constant connection to the server which will be a drain on the battery if running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Push services, i.e. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html
But there is a certain limit of pushes, I guess each second call would kill that limit. Maybe just send requests each 5 seconds, or 10 seconds? Temperature in the room doesn't change even at that rate :)

Comment: It's useful service, but another problem occurs when internet connection goes away. anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: This is an advantage of using GCM. Once the internet connection is back it will notify the device as soon as that happens.